# Disable Ginkgo warning of "slow test"

Tags: go, ginkgo

I am using Ginkgo to execute some relatively long-running integration tests. Interspersed with my test output is the occasional warning that my tests are taking too long to execute:

`• [SLOW TEST:30.000 seconds]`

Is there a way to disable these warnings when running Ginkgo through the standard Go testing library? The documentation mentions a parameter (`--slowSpecThreshold=TIME_IN_SECONDS`) for the Ginkgo test runner, but doesn't seem to mention how to achieve the same programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ginkgo v2, the `config.DefaultReporterConfig` variable has been [deprecated](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo/blob/f44af96315c960f07013723efcabcfa5f02c794f/config/deprecated.go#L66-L69) (see also the [migration guide](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/MIGRATING_TO_V2#changed-availability-of-ginkgos-configuration)) and cannot be used anymore to configure the "slow spec threshold".

To configure said threshold in Ginkgo v2, pass a `types.ReporterConfig` parameter into your `RunSpecs` call:

```golang
RunSpecs(t, "your test suite", types.ReporterConfig{
    SlowSpecThreshold: 10 * time.Second,
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Ginkgo handles its configuration in the `github.com/onsi/ginkgo/config` package, where the runtime configuration is available for modifications.

Making Ginkgo far more patient can be achieved with:

`config.DefaultReporterConfig.SlowSpecThreshold = time.Hour.Seconds()`

Comment: Where did you set this field exactly? I've tried setting it in my `func TestFoo(t *testing.T)` function, and in `BeforeSuite`, and whilst I can assert that the field has the right value, I'm still seeing slow test warnings.

Comment: @EngineerBetter_DJ: I'm setting it in the `TestSuite` setup function, where I also register before- and after-handlers etc.

Comment: Ha - so the reason I was getting confused is that it turns out that this doesn't work when running Ginkgo with `-p` for parallel test running! Thanks for your help.